# Javascript How to push a key value pair into a nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have this JSON response where I want to push **"status": "pending"**, inside the nested Menu array, Please help how I can achieve this in Javascript.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "menues": [
        {
            "title": "Coke",
            "price": "200"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "status": "delivered",
    "menues": [
        {
            "title": "Pepsi",
            "price": "120"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**Here is what I want to achieve:**
I just want to push the Staus key/value inside the Menu array

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "menues": [
        {
            "title": "Coke",
            "price": "200",
            "status": "pending",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "menues": [
        {
            "title": "Pepsi",
            "price": "120",
            "status": "delivered",
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can go over the array, and for each item, go over the items in `menues`. Using the `forEach` method, this can even be done as a single statement:

```js
arr = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "pending",
      "menues": [
          {
              "title": "Coke",
              "price": "200"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "status": "delivered",
      "menues": [
          {
              "title": "Pepsi",
              "price": "120"
          }
      ]
  }
];

arr.forEach(nested => {
    nested.menues.forEach(menu => menu.status = nested.status);
    delete nested.status
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What about if there are multiple statuses like he has another "status": "delivered" ?So always have to run multiple loops?

Comment: @hamzaliaqat no - just put the logic in inner `forEach` to decide what `status` to assign.

Comment: @Mureinik I think the OP has the desired status in the object itself, we just want to push it into the array while going through your loop

Comment: @kevmc oh, indeed! I completely missed the brief there. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @hamzaliaqat I misread the question. Thanks to kevmc pointing this out, I've edited my answer to provide the required functionality.

Comment: @Mureinik Is it possible with ES5 or ES6? Like with spread operator and map method?

Comment: @hamzaliaqat I can't think of a way the spread operator will help here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want? The following script creates a new nested array structure, leaving the original unchanged. Instead of deleting the `status` property from the outer object I limit the creation of properties in the newly created object to `id` and `menues`.

I changed this answer in response to OP's comment asking for ES5 and ES6 methods and the `...` operator.

```js
arr = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "pending",
      "menues": [
          {
              "title": "Coke",
              "price": "200"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "status": "delivered",
      "menues": [
          {
              "title": "Pepsi",
              "price": "120"
          }
      ]
  }
];

const res=arr.map(nested =>({ id:nested.id, menues:
  nested.menues.map(menu =>({...menu,status:nested.status})) }));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is it possible with ES5 or ES6? Like with spread operator and map method?

Comment: Please check again, I changed my answer.

Comment: thank you so much, there was an issue when I was applying the first solution with forEach loop but now it's worked perfect and saved my day, once again thank you for your valuable answer